# Calculate $\int_{\gamma} \sqrt z dz$ where $\gamma = C(2,1)^+$

Tags: integration, analysis

I'm new to complex analysis and I was hoping someone could explain me how to calculate these integrals:

Calculate $\int_{\gamma} \sqrt z  dz$ where $\gamma = C(2,1)^+$ where we are integrating over the principal value of $\sqrt z$.

What I did so far was:

$z(t) = 2 + e^{it}$ with $t \in [0,2\pi]$ so we get

$\int_{C(2,1)^+} \sqrt z  dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{2 + e^{it}} ie^{it}dt = \frac{2}{3}(2 + e^{it})^{\frac{2}{3}}|_{0}^{2\pi} = 0$.

Is this correct or is everything non-sense. 
Next question: now $\gamma = C(1,1)^+$ and what if $\gamma = C(0,1)^+$
But they would end up being $0$ too.

Comment: It looks just fine to me...and if you read some further pages ahead in your complex analysis text book, it fits with what you expect of an **analytic function** integrated over a closed, simple path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most general $C(x,r)^+$:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{x+re^{i\theta}}ire^{i\theta}{\rm d}\theta=\frac23(x+re^{i\theta})^{3/2}\Bigg|_0^{2\pi}=0$$
Do you know why? It is given in the form of a theorem known as **Cauchy-Goursat Theorem**:

> The theorem is usually formulated for closed paths as follows: let $\rm U$ be an open subset of $\rm C$ which is simply connected, let $\rm f : U → C$ be a holomorphic function, and let $\!\,\gamma$ be a rectifiable path in $\rm U$ whose start point is equal to its end point. Then
>
> $$\oint_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0. $$ from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).

Comment: Because we can split $\gamma$ into $2$ parts. Lets say $\gamma = \gamma_{1} + \gamma_2$. Then we know $\gamma_1$ and $-\gamma_2$ are two curves with the same begin and end point and thus $\int_{\gamma_1} f(z) dz = \int_{-\gamma_2} f(z) dz$. So we know $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = \int_{\gamma_1} f(z) dz + \int_{\gamma_2} f(z) dz = 0.$ Correct?

Comment: @Nescrio yes somethign like that.